# Can a Javascript condition be between numbers?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm looking to identify a category based on this table:
[image: Table]

I have an if statement that seems to work for some conditions, but not others. R, P, and Q are working, but conditions that go between numbers aren't returning the right category.

If statement:

```
function getCategory(featureFunctionalScore, featureDysfunctionalScore) {
    if (featureFunctionalScore == 4 && featureDysfunctionalScore == -2) {
        return "Performance";
    } else if (featureFunctionalScore == 4 && featureDysfunctionalScore <= -1 && featureDysfunctionalScore > 4) {
        return "Attractive"
    } else if (featureFunctionalScore <= -1 && featureFunctionalScore > 4 && featureDysfunctionalScore == 4) {
        return "Expected"
    } else if ((featureFunctionalScore >= -2 && featureFunctionalScore <= 2 && featureDysfunctionalScore == -2) || (featureFunctionalScore == -2 && featureDysfunctionalScore >= -2 && featureDysfunctionalScore <= 2)) {
        return "Reverse"
    } else if ((featureFunctionalScore == 4 && featureDysfunctionalScore == -2) || (featureFunctionalScore == 2 && featureDysfunctionalScore == -1) || (featureFunctionalScore == -1 && featureDysfunctionalScore == 2) || (featureFunctionalScore == -2 && featureDysfunctionalScore == 4)) {
        return "Questionable"
    } else {
        return "Indifferent"
    };
};
```

Am I missing something important?

**Update**
This statement works in Excel, but I'm struggling to get it to work in JS:

```
=IF(OR(AND(C3 <= 2, B3 <= -1), AND(C3 <= -1, B3 <= 2)), "R", IF(AND(C3 <= 2, C3 >= -1, B3 <= 2, B3 >= -1), "I", IF(AND(C3 >= 2,B3 >= -1, B3 <= 2),"A", IF(AND(C3 <= 2, B3 <= 4, B3 >= 2), "M", IF(AND(C3 >= 2, B3 >= 2), "P", "Q")))))
```

Comment: You have `else if (featureFunctionalScore == 4 && featureDysfunctionalScore <= -1 && featureDysfunctionalScore > 4)`.  This condition will never be true, because featureDysfunctionalScore can never be <=-1 *and* >4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for. I'm sure it could be optimized, but it works. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yxb7tr9n/

```
  function getCategory(x,y){
    var answer = -999;

    if (x == 4 && y == 4){
        answer = "p";
    }else if([-1,0,2].indexOf(x) >= 0 && y == 4){
        answer = "A";    
    }else if((x == -2 && y == 4) || (x == -1 && y == 2) || (x == 4, y == -2)){
        answer = "Q";    
    }else if(x == 4 && [-1,0,2].indexOf(y) >= 0) {
        answer = "M";        
    }else if((x == -1 && [-1,0].indexOf(y) >= 0) || (x == 0 && [-1,0,2].indexOf(y) >= 0) || (x == 2 && [0,2].indexOf(y) >= 0)){
        answer = "I";    
    }else if ((x == -2 && [-2,-1,0,2].indexOf(y) >= 0) || (y == -2 && [-2,-1,0,2].indexOf(x) >= 0)) {
        answer = "R";
    }else{
        answer = "??";
    }

    return answer;
  }
```

---

**UPDATE:** Alternate version using a coordinate mapping system. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g2d6p4rL/4/

```
  function indexOfCustom (parentArray, searchElement) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < parentArray.length; i++ ) {
      if ( parentArray[i][0] == searchElement[0] && parentArray[i][1] == searchElement[1] ) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }

  function getCategory2(x,y){    
    var p = [[4,4]];
    var q = [[-2,4],[-1,2],[2,-1],[4,-2]];
    var a = [[-1,4],[0,4],[2,4]];
    var m = [[4,2],[4,0],[4,-1]];
    var i = [[0,2],[2,2],[-1,0],[0,0],[2,0],[-1,-1],[0,-1]];
    var r = [[-2,2],[-2,0],[-2,-1],[-2,-2],[-1,-2],[0,-2],[2,-2]];

    coord = [x,y];

    if (indexOfCustom(p,coord) >= 0){
        return "p";
    } else if (indexOfCustom(q,coord) >= 0){
        return "Q";
    } else if (indexOfCustom(a,coord) >= 0){
        return "A";
    } else if (indexOfCustom(m,coord) >= 0){
        return "M";
    } else if (indexOfCustom(i,coord) >= 0){
        return "I";
    } else if (indexOfCustom(r,coord) >= 0){
        return "R";
    }else{
        return "??";
    }
  }
```

Output of all answers:

```
[-2,-2] = R
[-2,-1] = R
[-2,0] = R
[-2,2] = R
[-2,4] = Q
[-1,-2] = R
[-1,-1] = I
[-1,0] = I
[-1,2] = Q
[-1,4] = A
[0,-2] = R
[0,-1] = I
[0,0] = I
[0,2] = I
[0,4] = A
[2,-2] = R
[2,-1] = Q
[2,0] = I
[2,2] = I
[2,4] = A
[4,-2] = Q
[4,-1] = M
[4,0] = M
[4,2] = M
[4,4] = p
```

Comment: It needs to work with decimals between each coordinate. Can I achieve that with coordinates?

Comment: I added the formula that works in Excel. Still not working right in JS.

Comment: Sure, it's pretty simple to alter the function for that. For in-between values (decimal, "1", etc.), how do you want it treated? Should it be the floor, ceiling, or rounded?

Comment: Probably ceiling.

Comment: An Excel to JS converter spit this out, but I can't really read it. Is this valid JS code? 
`(((C3<=2&&B3<=-1)||(C3<=-1&&B3<=2))?"R":((C3<=2&&C3>=-1&&B3<=2&&B3>=-1)?"I":((C3>=2&&B3>=-1&&B3<=2)?"A":((C3<=2&&B3<=4&&B3>=2)?"M":((C3>=2&&B3>=2)?"P":"Q")))))`

Comment: I'm not sure. It might be valid but it's not legible, so if you have to modify it in the future you'll have to punch it into that Excel to JS generator again.

Comment: To have my function work for in-between values, just change `coord = [x,y]` to `coord = [Math.ceil(x),Math.ceil(y)]`